# Eclipse Servlet .class does not refresh when i change the .java source

Tags: eclipse, servlets

I am new to Eclipse, i know that in windows environment i would recompile the changed source code and put the .class file in the classes directory it belongs. In eclipse i change the code and restart the server but it seems the .class file remains unchanged, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Rephrase your question to make it clearer and include concrete directories and sequences of actions

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70165377/4879593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case try to clean your project and rebuild it.

You will get these options in **Project** menu of eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Try these options ..

Menu - Project  -  clean (Click this option if Build Automatically is not used)

Menu - Project   -  Project Build Automatically (Check this option)

These can help you.

[Using the Eclipse Workbench](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/workbench.html)

[Servlet and JSP development with Eclipse](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html)