# Though I have setMaster as local, my spark application gives error

Tags: apache-spark

I have the following application (I am starting and stopping spark) in Windows. I use Scala-IDE(Eclipse). I get "A master URL must be set in your configuration" error even though I have set it here. I use spark-2.4.4 version.

Can someone please help me to fix this issue.

```
import org.apache.spark._;
import org.apache.spark.sql._;

object SampleApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {    
    val conf =  new SparkConf()
               .setMaster("local[*]")
               .setAppName("Simple Application")

    val sc   =  new SparkContext(conf)

    sc.stop()
  }

}
```

The error is:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
19/10/28 22:58:56 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.4
19/10/28 22:58:56 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/10/28 22:58:56 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at com.spark.renga.SampleApp$.main(SampleApp.scala:8)
    at com.spark.renga.SampleApp.main(SampleApp.scala)
19/10/28 22:58:56 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.postApplicationEnd(SparkContext.scala:2416)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$stop$2(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at com.spark.renga.SampleApp$.main(SampleApp.scala:8)
    at com.spark.renga.SampleApp.main(SampleApp.scala)
19/10/28 22:58:56 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at com.spark.renga.SampleApp$.main(SampleApp.scala:8)
    at com.spark.renga.SampleApp.main(SampleApp.scala)
```

Comment: What are your spark-submit options?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using version 2.4.4 try this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SampleApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("test")
      .getOrCreate()

    println(spark.sparkContext.version)

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with your code. Unfortunately I got the same error.

Comment: I use Scala Eclipse-IDE for development. It looks like my changes in the file are NOT detected by the IDE. I tried some options mentioned in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509214/in-eclipse-the-changes-of-my-source-code-have-no-effect  and few worked!